Checking directory using variable in Linux
A bit confusion I am facing
A script which is a question in kodecloud I am trying to check if the directory exists using if else statement
the directory exists but when using varilable it gives answer that Directory not found
dir="/home/bob/caleston"
  
if [ -d $dir ]
then
        echo "Directory exists"
else
        echo "Directory not found"
fi

But if I do not use a variable it will print Directory exists
if [ -d "/home/bob/caleston" ]
then
        echo "Directory exists"
else
        echo "Directory not found"
fi

Any reason for this that why using variable is giving wrong answer?
I tried different methods of using variable but it still showed the wrong answer, when adding the whole path in the if statementg it prints the correct answer.

Use set -x (within the script, or bash -x yourscript to turn it on from that end) to enable trace logging, and compare the logs both ways.

If for example the log for the one from the variable is [ -d $'/home/bob/caleston\r' ], then you know your variable was read from a file saved with DOS newlines.

Or if the log shows [ -d home bob caleston ], then you know the problem is that your code was run with IFS=/ and inadequate quoting (that particular problem is one that [ -d "$dir" ] wouldn't have).

...but there are multiple possible causes, and there's no way we can distinguish between them without a log.

I see, thanks for set -x way to check, so is it possible the platform I Am using has defined it somehow to not read from a variable like as you suggested the code was run with IFS=/ ?

And thank you so much Charles

Let's start with getting an actual trace log, and hypothesize about what could cause a particular behavior after we know which behavior it is that you're seeing.

Sure will check it this way thanks again sir

You are using double quotes exactly wrong.  Instead of dir="/p/a/t/h"; test [ -d $dir ]; ...., you want to quote the expansion of the variable.  eg dir=/p/a/t/h; test [ -d "$dir" ].  There's nothing wrong with dir="/p/a/t/h", and best practice encourages quoting the string on the right, but failing to use quotes in test [ -d "$dir" ] is almost always not what you intend.

I see, so rather then using double quotes in the variable I should have used it in the if statement for the variable"$dir"

Or just always use the quotes in both places. As William says it's safe to skip them in an assignment where the content couldn't be treated as syntactic, and always appropriate to use them on expansion unless you have a specific reason not to. That said, as long as /home/bob/caleston is your real variable value and IFS is at defaults, I wouldn't expect that to cause the immediate problem in this particular case.

Alright thank you Charles and William for this

IFS doesn't change by itself, there would have to be an earlier line in the script that reassigns it.

Start by pasting your code into shellcheck.net, and fix the problems it finds.

an additional debugging approach ... just before the if/then/else add typeset -p dir to display the contents of the variable as seen by bash

...though the typeset -p output should be entirely duplicative with what we'd get from set -x.

@Barmar, ...could have had a non-default value explicitly exported to the environment by a parent process, in theory. Though I still expect that we'll actually see something more like DOS newlines or fancy Unicode quotes or a trailing non-breaking space instead of a "real"/ASCII space, &c.

@CharlesDuffy "in theory" -- true. In practice, very unlikely. I'll bet any amount it's DOS newlines.

Indeed. Given the lack of responsiveness (re: getting a trace log to rule out the unlikely oddball causes), I somewhat regret not closing it as a duplicate of the regular canonical instance (Are shell scripts sensitive to encodings and line endings?) up-front.

In your concrete example, there should be no difference betwwen the too. In the general case (i.e. depending on the name of the direcrory), you would have to test the existence of the directory by either [[ -d $dir ]] or [[ -d "$dir" ]].

@Barmar : If there would be wrong line endings, wouldn't the [ command produce an error message (since the last argument thenisn't ], but a bracket, followed by a CR). But the OP doesn't mention any error message.

@user1934428 I suspect the code in the question is simplified from the real thing. The real script may be reading the directory name from a file, and CRLF is in that file, not the script itself. Or something else has caused the assignment line to have a CRLF, but not the rest of the script.
